# Meteor JS return undefined object in findOne Function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have created a project in `MeteorJS`, now I am trying to fetch record as per my requirement, I am using following query

`db.getCollection('parcels').findOne({"barcode" : "484847u4u"})`

It's working fine in MongoDB and return data, but If same query I am using in `MeteorJS` and it's return `Nil` object.

I read lots of issue regarding same thing like [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49627152/meteor-files-findone-return-undefined),  [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47002250/meteor-mongo-findone-function-returning-undefined), etc...but can't get any solution.

/////Updated :

```
    API Box: Parcels.js
    ------
    import { Mongo }        from 'meteor/mongo';
    export const Parcels = new Mongo.Collection('parcels');
    Meteor.methods({
            'parcels.checkBarcode': (parcelId) => {
      // find
          const parcel = Parcels.findOne(parcelId);
         // const parcels =  Parcels.findOne({ barcode : barcode }, {});
       return parcel;
     },
  });

  ParcelList.js
  -----
  import { Parcels } from '/imports/api/parcels.js';
  Parcels.findOne({barcode: "48484747u4u"})
```

Comment: Where are you running `findOne()`? Server-side or client-side? If client-side, do you have any code that prevents the client from reading those records? Is the records published?

Comment: `Parcels.findOne()` should either return undefined or a complete object. Please show your Meteor code for the query, your publication and collection definitions

Comment: If this is on the client, it's most likely that you are calling the function before the data has been sent from the server. You should use the `ready` callback on a subscription to call this at the right time. If you edit your question to include more information about where the function is called, and your publications/subscriptions, then we can help you properly

Comment: @d4nyll I have updated code..

Comment: @Mikkel this is for Server side

Comment: This code looks fine - what doesn't work about it? `console.log(Parcels.findOne({barcode: "48484747u4u"}))` Are you sure you are connecting to the right database?

Comment: @Mikkel yes, we are connecting right db...Thanks for your response.

Comment: What happens if you run just ```Parcels.findOne()``` ? Does that return an object? Or is that also returning ```undefined```

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct, so the only real possibility would be that you're not connecting to the correct DB. MeteorJS by default has it's own local DB, so while you might think you have it setup correctly, if you do in fact have it setup wrong then Meteor will just use it's own version of DB.

The best way to test it is to do an 'insert' with Meteor and if the document doesn't appear in the intended DB, then you haven't set it up correctly.

Also for future reference, make sure you use Meteor's "check" package. Passing the value directly into the query opens you to NoSQL injection. In your example, 'parcelID' could be passed from the client as any 'object' and do any query a malicious person wanted.